# Write ListObjects to and specific format file

Tags: c#, json, list, file, listobject

i want to serialize a List and write it to a file in a specific way, but im unable to do so right now my file comes this way:

```
  ["ENS FRUTAS",
"REST",
"CENAS",
"$26.50","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
"1",
"$26.50"]
```

But i need it like this

```
[
  {
    "Descripcion": "ENS FRUTAS","Pdv": "REST","Rid": "CENAS","PV": "$26.50","1": "0",
    "2": "1","3": "0","4": "0","5": "1","6": "0","7": "0","8": "1","9": "0","10": "0",
    "11": "1","12": "0","13": "0","14": "1","15": "0","16": "0","17": "1","18": "0",
    "19": "0","20": "1","21": "0","22": "0","23": "1","24": "0","25": "0","26": "1",
    "27": "0","28": "0","29": "0","30": "1","31": "0","Total": "1","Venta": "$26.50",

  }]
```

How can i make my file to be like the second format?
this is my Serialized action:

```
 List<object> list = new List<object>();

                foreach (var item in db.Pos)
                   {
                        var total = 0;
                        decimal costo = 0;

                       for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
                            {
                            var value = 0;
                             if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; costo = costo + item.Total; }
                                                        total += value;
                             }
                                                       list.Add(item.Descripcion);
                                                       list.Add(item.Pdv);
                                                       list.Add(item.Rid);
                                                       list.Add(((costo / (total + 1)).ToString("C")));
                                                        for (int i = 1; i <= 31; i++)
                                                        {
                                                            var value = 0;
                                                            list.Add(value);
                                                            int month = item.Fecha.Month;
                                                            if (item.Fecha.Day == i) { value = item.Cantidad; list.Add(value); }

                                                        }
                     list.Add(total);
                     list.Add((((costo / (total + 1)) * total).ToString("C")));
                            }
 var javaScriptSerializer = new
            System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(list);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\path.txt", jsonString);
```

Comment: how does your list look like?

Comment: Instead of writing all the text at once, you could obviously split the jsonstring before hand and then iterate over all the indices in the array

Comment: That is so hard to read. Why not a line feed after each comma?

Comment: What type of object do you add to your list, could you add it to your example?

Comment: i just added the complete List Loop and serialized action @LarsN

Comment: I can't make sense of the second for(int i...) there is only one value (item.Cantidad) that you add but in your wanted output, it varies between 0 and 1.

Comment: The second for loops put's "0s" on the next 31 characters and put 1 on the character that equals the day, the characters that start from 1 -31 are days and the for iterates the data and put 0 in each day unles theres a value witch then puts a 1 and then continue to fil the other days with 0 and finish with Total and Venta